# Numpy array rounding not working

Tags: python, numpy, rounding

Dear Python community,

I am trying to interpolate between data points, but **would like to keep my results to 3 decimals**, so I defined the following function :

```
import numpy

def spline(y, x , xnew):
    from scipy import interpolate 
    model = interpolate.splrep(x,y)
    ynew  = interpolate.splev(xnew,model)
    result = ynew.round(3)

    return result
```

which seems to give me the expected result on the following simple example :

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,7,10]
y = [1.31,1.883,2.285,2.572,2.809,3.024,3.208]
z = spline(y,x, np.arange(1,11))
```

which yields the expected :

```
Out[109]: 
array([ 1.31 ,  1.883,  2.285,  2.572,  2.809,  2.954,  3.024,  3.062,
        3.109,  3.208])
```

BUT, when I tried to retrieve a particular value, it does not seem to be rounded. How can I solve this please ?

```
z[3]
Out[110]: 2.5720000000000001
```

Following answers below I tried :

```
t= 2.572
t
Out[119]: 2.572
type(t)
Out[120]: float
```

so I don't understand why now it can have exactly 2.572 or is there an implicit 3 decimals display property in my definition of t ?

Comment: That is known behavior of any programming language. It happens because exact representation of the decimal number 2.572 requires an infinite number binary digits

Comment: Thus, `2.5720000000000001` is the closest to `2.572` that can be represented by a Python `float`.

Comment: What is your actual use case? Do you _really_ need it to be exactly three decimals? Then you should consider using the `Decimal` class.

Comment: Thanks, I can survive wit that, I just find it irritating when debugging. Also why don't I get the same problem when I tell python
    t= 2.572
    t
    Out[119]: 2.572
    type(t)
    Out[120]: float

Comment: The reason lays in the `repr()` implementation. I don't know the details, but when writing a `float` Python decides to not show the value to that level of exactness. However, the `repr()` of `np.double()` (which has the same precision) uses more decimals. And when using `numpy` your values will be  `np.double`:s. If you do `float(z[3])` you will be converting your `np.double` to a standard Python `float` and it will display with only three decimal digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is known behavior of any programming language. It happens because exact representation of the decimal number 2.572 requires an infinite number binary digits

If you would like to display just 3 decimal places, you can use the `str.format()` function:

```
'{0:.3f}'.format(z[3])
```